# Apply git patch created with git diff

Tags: git, apply, diff, patch, format-patch

I am trying to move uncommited changes from a local git repository to another local repository.
On repo 1 I create a patch like this:

```
git diff > my_patch.patch
```

Inspecting the patch:

```
more my_patch.patch
```

I get the same output as running `git diff`  on the first repo.
In the second repo I run:

```
git apply --stat my_patch.patch
0 files changed
```

If I run `git apply my_patch.patch` I get no effect.
Am I creating the patch wrong? Am I applying it wrong?

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Clone a repository 2 times (same branch checkout)
2. In first repo, make some changes to a file (uncommited).
3. Create patch from changes: `git diff > ~/my_patch.patch`
4. Go to second repository. Try and apply patch: `git apply ~/my_patch.patch`
5. Run `git status`. No changes!

Suggesting another way of moving uncommited changes to another local repo would also be good to solve my issue.

Comment: It would help if you created a [mcve]. Note that `git apply --stat` tells you what *would* change, without applying, as it disables the `--apply` option.

Comment: I know, I just wanted to show that git will not make any change from the .patch file.

Comment: If I try your 5 steps, the result is that `git status` shows me `Changes not staged for commit` in the modified file, and `git diff` in the clone in which the patch is applied shows the same patch I applied with `git apply`.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. The patch applies on the clone and I see the differences applied there.

Answer (score 4):

Not only your usecase now (Q4 2021, Git 2.34+) is working as expected, but Git 2.35 (Q1 2022), "[`git apply`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/62a3a27b915c5f2a70796af15678cce1079d200a/Documentation/git-apply.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply))</sup> has also been taught to ignore a message without a patch with the `--allow-empty` option.
And it learned to honor the `--quiet` option given from the command line.

See [commit 324eb77](https://github.com/git/git/commit/324eb77ee76277be99bdc54ef0b74ff30f5f567b), [commit c21b8ae](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c21b8ae857d0d58b67ca77384ccc1880d834c2d5) (13 Dec 2021) by [Jerry Zhang (`jerry-skydio`)](https://github.com/jerry-skydio).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 62a3a27](https://github.com/git/git/commit/62a3a27b915c5f2a70796af15678cce1079d200a), 22 Dec 2021)</sup>

> ### [`git-apply`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/324eb77ee76277be99bdc54ef0b74ff30f5f567b): add `--allow-empty` flag
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jerry Zhang</sup>

> Some users or scripts will pipe "[`git diff`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/324eb77ee76277be99bdc54ef0b74ff30f5f567b/Documentation/git-diff.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff))</sup> output to [`git apply`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/324eb77ee76277be99bdc54ef0b74ff30f5f567b/Documentation/git-apply.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply))</sup> when replaying diffs or commits.
> In these cases, they will rely on the return value of "`git apply`" to know whether the diff was applied successfully.
>
> However, for empty commits, "`git apply`" will fail.
> This complicates scripts since they have to either buffer the diff and check its length, or run diff again with "exit-code", essentially doing the diff twice.
>
> Add the "`--allow-empty`" flag to "`git apply`" which allows it to handle both empty diffs and empty commits created by [`git format-patch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/324eb77ee76277be99bdc54ef0b74ff30f5f567b/Documentation/git-format-patch.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch))</sup> `--always` by doing nothing and returning 0.

`git apply` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/324eb77ee76277be99bdc54ef0b74ff30f5f567b/Documentation/git-apply.txt#L19):

> [--verbose | --quiet] [--unsafe-paths] [--allow-empty] [...]

`git apply` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/324eb77ee76277be99bdc54ef0b74ff30f5f567b/Documentation/git-apply.txt#L259-L262):

> ### `--allow-empty`
>
> Don't return error for patches containing no diff.
> This includes empty patches and patches with commit text only.